# How to install node_module?

Tags: npm, node-modules

I installed nodejs and verions are:

[image: npm]

Wben I tried for install `node_module`, I did not solve my problem. I get this error in terminal.

[image: node]

Answer (score 1):

**1-**

you have to run `npm init -y` to generate **package.json** file then run `npm install` to install dependencies.

**2-**

but if you download or clone a project from ***github*** or other server , you have to see the **dependencies** and **devDependencies** in package.json file

after all these things run `npm install` to install your own **dependencies**

Comment: I get this messages: i.stack.imgur.com/fdktj.png

Comment: yeah, now the package.json file is created

Comment: if you have dependencies inside package.json then when you run `npm install` then the folder `node_module` generated

Answer (score 0):

You have to run "npm init" in the terminal for your code editor next time you need it for a project. It will create a JSON file for you and the node_modules folder will be created, where the modules ("Javascript files") will be stored. You probably haven't imported any modules yet, which is why the node_modules folder isn't on your computer yet.

Hope this answer helps!

Comment: I get this messages: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSfaC.png

Comment: run '`npm init -y`

Comment: I get this messages: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdktj.png

Comment: That's not an error. That shows that `npm init` was successful.